# Javascript null variable in asp.net inline

Tags: javascript, asp.net, webforms

In my asp.net  page  `FieldId` is the page-class level variable in code behind

```
protected int? FieldId= null;
```

Then I try to set the same value to the Javascript variable, so whenever page gets loaded I can access the same in Javascript and do some stuff

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var searchFieldId = '<%= FieldId %>';
</script>
```

Whenever I have a `FieldId` value **null** the page renders like below

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    var searchFieldId = ; // but here i need null
</script>
```

Since the variable initialization has the improper syntax i get syntax error.

How do we write null here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a workaround like the following in C#:

```
var searchFieldId = <%= (FieldId.HasValue ? FieldId.Value.ToString() : "null") %>;
```

or VB:

```
var searchFieldId = <%= If(FieldId.HasValue, FieldId.Value.ToString(), "null") %>;
```

Comment: It renders as `var searchFieldId = 'null'; ` But i need to be `var searchFieldId = null;`, without a quotes